# Objects of a class derived from an abstract class should be in free store?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I'm trying to wrap my head around what seems to be strange to me in TC++PL. It is about allocation of a class derived from an abstract class.

> Since we don't know anything about the representation of an abstract type, **we must allocate objects on the free store** and access them through references and pointers.

Why free store? As you already know, a class derived from an abstract class can be allocated like any other local variables. I have no idea what exactly TC++PL tries to convey in this sentence.

Comment: Maybe this applies to a specific context, such as polymorphic data members or arrays?

Comment: @Jefffrey I mean The C++ Programming Language by Bajarne Stroustrup. I thought everybody knows. Sorry about that.

Comment: _'It is about instantiation of an abstract class.'_ In c++ you simply **can't instantiate** abstract classes!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "a class derived from an abstract class can be allocated"

Comment: But as the wording stands, it's incorrect though!

Comment: @Jarod42, true. It wouldn't make much sense in the context, but true.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is an incorrect statement. For example if you have an abstract base class B and derived (non-abstract) class D then you can write

```
D d;
B &b = d;
```

that is object of type D is created in stack provided that this code is in some function.

Comment: C++ has no notion of *stack*.

Comment: @Jefffrey From the C++ standard "Alternatively, an implementation could allocate such an array on the usual stack or obtain storage via malloc" or "The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed on the path from a try block to the
point where an exception is thrown is called “stack unwinding.”"

Comment: @Jefffrey From the context of the quetion it is clear enough.

Comment: Some implementations of course make use of a *stack*, not all. In fact **an implementation** is the key point there. Also *stack unwinding* has little to do with *stack* vs *heap* that you are trying to imply here.

Comment: @Jefffrey You are mitaken. There is no such notion as "heap unwinding". It is applied only to stacks.

Comment: Can you show me where *stack allocation* is described in details in the standard (not just few phrases where the word "stack" happens to appear)? I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Jeff _'Can you should me where'_?? English please (did you mean _point_?) ...

Comment: @Jefffre There is no details because C++ is described for an abstract mashine. Nevertheless the term stack is used in the standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you're kind of missing the point here. When Bjarne says `we must allocate objects on the free store` he is giving _advice_ on how to conduct coding in CPP, instead of explaining that advice and the importance of indirect access vs direct access in CPP and how to conduct access you stuck to a technical inaccuracy. Please consider revising your answer.

Answer (score 0):

They mean that if you want to use some abstract class without knowing what concrete type that is, you must use dynamic allocation for it, i.e that you cannot write `abstract_class A = concrete_class B;`